# How to get individual conference report using Office 365 Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

Using the following Rest API link, we are getting the overall report for SFB Online usage:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/report

Can anyone help me getting the detailed report of an individual conference?
I need the following information about a conference:

- Start time of the Conference
- No. of participants
- Each participant join time and logout time
- Each participant joined by audio/video
- Conference end time
- No. of Participant joined as Guest
- Participant's client information etc.

We tried in below both ways using REST API calls:

- reports.office365.com/ecp/reportingwebservice/reporting.svc

  In this case, we receive Status Code as 200 OK but response content is nil for SFB calls where as we are receiving content for exchange API calls.
- graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports

  In this case, we are receiving the SFB overall usages. However, we are not getting any rest API to fetch details about the individual conference.

Please share the proper link so that I can get proper Rest API to proceed with my work.

Comment: hi! did you manage to get this information? I can't find any endpoint to get it either

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. We tried to contact Microsoft and ended up with no conclusion. As the Microsoft Graph is still in development phase, so dropped the plan to use Microsoft Graph.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Did you end up using another API or completely dropped the idea of getting this data?

Comment: When we were trying, Microsoft Graph's Preview version was released. So, most of the API were not exposed. Then we tried to use UCWA, then tried Trusted API. Finally, we dropped the plan to use Microsoft APIs. However, Microsoft might have exposed more API Since then. I didn't try anytime now to achieve the same.

Comment: thanks for sharing you experience, I'll keep an eye on new APIs